# Improved jumps to definition

Tags: plugins, vim, ctags

When we're using `ctags` in `vim` and want to go to particular definition of variable or function we press `ctrl + ]`, when we want to go back we press `ctrl + T`.

When we want to autocomplete a name of a variable we press `ctrl + N` and from a [little violet window](http://wiki.oseems.com/application/vim/enable-auto-complete?) we can choose the right word.

Is it possible to improve `go to definition` so that we won't jump in the document, but only the little window with the function or variable definition will appear?

thank you

Comment: Are you looking for `:set completeopt+=preview`?

Comment: @RandyMorris I tried it but don't have a feeling that this option do something with `go to definition` when I press `ctrl + ]`

Comment: Try `Ctrl-W` followed by `}` instead of `Ctrl-]`.

Comment: @RandyMorris This is opening another split window, not the small balloon as is in romainis answer.

Comment: Balloons are not possible in console vim.

Comment: @RandyMorris By balloons I mean the same window that appears when you type `ctrl+N` while doing autocompletion.

Answer (score 2):

You want a way to see the function's signature without actually jumping to its definition?

I know about two plugins supposed to provide exactly this feature:

- [EchoFunc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1735),
- [Tag Signature Balloons](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2714)

The last time I tried echofunc it didn't work for JavaScript, at least for me, but it worked well for the few PHP files I've tested it with. I didn't try the other one because it's GVim-only and I use the CLI version almost as often as the GUI version.

But you can also use TagList and/or TagBar: two very useful plugins providing great code navigation based on ctags. Both will display the signature of the tag under your cursor if you hit `<Space>`.

Comment: Thank you, it's on a good way, but I'm using only CLI version of vim and most of the time work with Python, C, Javascript. It should show the whole function definition when I move the cursor above function call (if the function is not too large). But the scripts you're suggesting look good and I will study them if nothing better exists yet.

Comment: If you use tags to navigate through your code, there is [a good page on the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags) you will find interesting. Especially the "How do I preview a tag?" part.

Comment: @romaini I'd like to see the preview in the same window which appears during autocompletion when pressing `ctrl+N`. It works in CLI vim and disappears quickly when you start typing.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know a way to show that popup menu outside of omni-completion context: all the tools I know that show signatures use either a message in the command line or a small preview window with the exception of the "balloon" plugin. The most effective ways to show the signature of a function are IMO the `<Space>` trick in TagList/TagBar or the built-in `<C-w>}` has indicated by Randy Morris.